# (Lyx) How to add a graphic to titlepage

Tags: lyx

I'm using mostly standard setting, artlcle class, custom=titlepage. I generate a separate titlepage, and separate abstract page.

I would like to add a graphic to the titlepage, either between title and author, or below author. How do I do this with Lyx?

Comment: Is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148576/lyxarticle-document-image-under-title-in-front-page helpful?

Comment: yes, thanks. I tried a search earlier but used "graphic" instead of "image".